# exc_breakpoint (code=exc_i386_bpt subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift

For some reason, my program crashes, displaying this error for both these lines of code

Line Error 1)

```
@IBAction func doneTapped(sender: AnyObject)
{
  var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))
  if (randomNumber == 1) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueLib1", sender: nil)
    }

  else{
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueLib2", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Line Error 2)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

   var madLibs1 = segue.destinationViewController as MadLib1ViewController

   var madLibs2 = segue.destinationViewController as MadLib2ViewController
```

I'm aiming to randomly segue between two view controllers, MadLib1ViewController and MadLib2ViewController, as doneTapped is pressed.However, whenever the button is tapped, it instead crashes and displays:

```
exc_breakpoint (code=exc_i386_bpt subcode=0x0)
```

I have eliminated all physical, blue breakpoints in the code. Can someone explain to me the error or and how to resolve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `performSegue` should send `self` in the second parameter.

If it's not that, you should know that breakpoints could be of exception type. Maybe your next view has a constraint exception and you're breaking on that. I would try "spamming" the "Skip breakpoint" button to see if that is the issue.

Before doing that, could you highlight the *exact* line of the crash? ( just add `//This line causes crash` ) right next to the crashing line.

Answer (score 0):

For 1), You should call "performSegue" with self as sender, not nil.

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueLib1", sender: self)
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueLib2", sender: self)
```

Your code at point 2) should be :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
  if (segue.identifier == 'segueLib1') {
    var madLibs1 = segue.destinationViewController as MadLib1ViewController
  else if (segue.identifier == 'segueLib2') {
    var madLibs2 = segue.destinationViewController as MadLib2ViewController
  }

  // Do something with your var
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've experienced this while using a breakpoint which would log something and then continue automatically. Disabled that, and things returned to normal. As the message suggests, it's a breakpoint issue

Try deleting all breakpoints